# How to bind multiple keyboard buttons to a widget in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simplest calculator and I want to operate it with the keyboard. This is the [file](https://github.com/Adityasingh76/Adityasingh76).
I want that whenever I press any number button or a sign button it insert to Entry widget and it does nothing if any button other than number button or sign button is pressed. I want to put all the code in the keyboardbutton function.
Sorry for less comments in the code. And thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should just include the code the question imo

Comment: When I add the code it says your post mostly contains code add some more details

Comment: Ah fair enough it is a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I made a list in `__init__` that matched your `self.lst` but where all characters are strings:

```
self.STR_LIST = list(map(str, self.lst))
```

Next, I bound keypresses to your tkinter window, so that the `keyboardbutton` mehtod will be called whenever a key is pressed (also in `__init__`):

```
self.window.bind("<Key>", self.keyboardbutton)
```

Then this should work for your `keyboardbutton` method:

```
def keyboardbutton(self, event):
    if event.char in self.STR_LIST:
        self.insert(event.char)
```

When a key is pressed, an event is sent to this method and we just simply check if it is a valid character for entry, then call your `insert` method.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.I also added some code so that it works with backspace and clear button also.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer